# How to set div height to fit the screen css

Tags: html, css

on high resolution screen it is ok and all content is viewable: http://prntscr.com/bo3rf4

but on lower resolution :http://prntscr.com/bo3rmw
the content below is hidden with footer overlay

and I want to make it fit to screen size with css
also I don't want to make overflow of body
i tried background-size setting to cover but nothing happen

you can find source on : http://devserv.5gbfree.com/eune.html - i cant add more than 2 links so make it http^^

```
<div class="ov-top masthead">

    <div class="content center">    
        <div class="contop">
                <p class="yellow_text"> Hello! </p>
                <div><a class="gumb" href="index.html" >SELECT SERVER</a></div>
            </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>


            <div class="concen"></div>
        </div>
```

---

```
    .ov-top, .page-top, .signup-main, .thanks-top {
padding-top: 180px;
padding-bottom: 15px;

}
.center {
 text-align: center;
 }
.content {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
 .masthead h1.heading-shadow {
position: absolute;
width: inherit;
text-shadow: 0 0 7px #010a13;
color: rgba(1,10,19,0);
background: 0 0;
z-index: 1;


}
.masthead h1 {
margin-top: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
cursor: default;


}
.changelog .head .title, .headline1, .masthead h1 {
font-family: "Beaufort for LOL";
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 60px;
color: #f0e6d2;
letter-spacing: 0;
line-height: 75px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom: 60px;
background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#e5cda0 0,#e5cda0 10px,#79622b 60px,#79622b 75px);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;


}

.contcen {
background: rgba(6, 29, 37, 0.87);
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
}
}
.contop {
background-color: rgba(6, 13, 19, 0.89);
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 20px;
position: absolute;
display: inline;
background-size: cover;

}
.cont {
border: 2px solid #033f47;
background: #021a1e;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 25px auto;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
width: 790px;
height: 600px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(4, 47, 53, 0.83);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(4, 47, 53, 0.83);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(4, 47, 53, 0.83);
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
background-size: cover;

}


.yellow_text {
color: #ccc1a0;
width: 790px;
height: 50px;
margin: -30px  auto ;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
padding: 13px ;
border: 2px solid #033f47;
background: #03232a;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(4, 47, 53, 0.83);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(4, 47, 53, 0.83);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(4, 47, 53, 0.83);
}
```

Comment: post your code to see where you are missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do some tweaking from your site. Try changing your `.cont`'s `height` to `calc(100vh - 300px)`.

```
.cont {
    height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}
```

It gets the browsers window height and subtract it to `300px` (just a test value but it works).

Comment: yep I will play with this a little bit, but certainly that's it, tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
.your-div{
    height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: top parent or selected where is text?

Answer (score 0):

You could create this easily using flexbox.  I tried this in ie and chrome and it gave sort of the look of your site.  It's a simple layout mock but it looks similar.

```
<html>

<head></head>

<style type="text/css">

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:not(.nav):not(.footer):not(.ov-top) {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.ov-top {
    flex: 3 1 0;
    background-color: black;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    width: 1000px;
    height: inherit;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="nav"></div>

        <div></div>

        <div class="ov-top masthead">
            <div class="content center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            </div>
        </div>


        <div></div>

        <div class="footer"></div>

    </div>


    </div>
</body>
```